# only part of a website displayed

Tags: html, css, iframe

As my website pertains to online magazines, I'd like to know how I can display only certain parts of the article. The articles are regular html with a global css linked to them. No pictures. Just text. How can I select a certain bit of this text and display it on another page? Other than doing it manually. Yes, the articles and the page are on the same server. I tried using iframes. Thing is, the height is set to a fixed value and overflow is hidden; so, sometimes the text is cut in half. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you know back-end programming? You could easily do it with a language like php. Another method is to make an AJAX call to the whole page using a javascript library(easier) or your own AJAX script. And then extracting the information you require.

Comment: Yea, I'm afraid it's difficult to answer your question with any recommended techniques, because what you are describing is entirely the wrong way to go about it. This sort of thing needs to be handled on the backend.

Comment: Please explain your issue a little better. Why do iframes not work? Why can't you adjust the height? Is there a website that does something similar to what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `onload()` of the `Iframe` to run a function to look at the height of the article, ad adjust the height of the `iframe` to match.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your issue correctly i woulde belive this will do it: 
Set overflow auto to give it a scrollbar or you can just use minimum height.